# Search for any node in non binary tree and keep their parents intact even if multiple nodes are found

Tags: java, tree, stream

I am trying to build an algorithm which will search for some nodes in tree against any search query. 
For example in our application tree is populated with all the nodes including  **two** nodes with the name **Roles** one belongs to a parent name **Data** and the other one belongs to a parent name **System**. Now if i provide a **roles** search criteria, tree should be filtered with both the Roles having their parents on them and remove all other nodes like this:

```
 Data
     -> Roles
 System
     -> Roles
```

I have been trying hard to get such result but with my current algorithm that i developed

```
  private TreeNodeDTO filterTree(String search,TreeNodeDTO    
    treeNodeDTO)
  {
    if ( treeNodeDTO.getTitle().equalsIgnoreCase( search ) ) {
        return treeNodeDTO;
    }
    List< TreeNodeDTO > children = treeNodeDTO.getChildren();
    TreeNodeDTO treeNodeDTOResult = null;
        for ( int i = 0; treeNodeDTOResult == null && i <   children.size(); i++ ) {
            treeNodeDTOResult = filterTree( search, children.get( i  ) );
        }
    return treeNodeDTOResult;
  }
```

i get only first found nodes which is not the requirement.

```
Data
 -> Roles
```

While i need following result

```
 Data
     -> Roles
 System
     -> Roles
```

I also have tried to modify existing tree structure to keep the track of parents and children and set flags to keep the track of parents but still i stuck at populating the end result.

**This is my treeNode class**

```
 public class TreeNodeDTO {

  /** The id. */
  private String id;

 /** The title. */
 private String title;

 /** The children. */
 private List<TreeNodeDTO> children;

 //setters and getters
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have modified your search algorithm so that it is now a member of the class TreeNodeDTO, which is a better object-oriented approach. Also, the search must return a list like this:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class TreeNodeDTO {

    /** The id. */
    private String id;

    /** The title. */
    private String title;

    /** The children. */
    private List<TreeNodeDTO> children;

    private List<TreeNodeDTO> recursiveSearch(String search) {
        if ( getTitle().equalsIgnoreCase( search ) ) {
            return Arrays.asList(this);
        }
        ArrayList<TreeNodeDTO> resultList = new ArrayList<>();
        for (TreeNodeDTO child : getChildren()) {
            resultList.addAll(child.recursiveSearch(search));
        }
        return resultList;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public List<TreeNodeDTO> getChildren() {
        return children;
    }

}
```